# how to extract the 2nd number in a string

Tags: r, string, stringr

I want to extract only the second number (in order) from a string.

```r
string = "vancomycin 1G IV 3 times a day over 1 hour."
```

desired output = 3

Comment: In which language?

Comment: using R language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A posssible solution, but not the prettiest one

```r
str_extract_all(string, "\\d+")[[1]][2]
```